# How can I see all properties (including inherited) in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

When working with nodejs, I like to use `console.log` to see what data is available in an object.

However, this doesn't work with inherited properties:

```
var Person = function () {};
Person.prototype.name = "anonymous";
var p = new Person();

console.log(['p', p]); // [ 'p', {} ]
// This doesn't even give me a hint that it's inherited from Person!
console.log(['typeof p', typeof p]); // [ 'typeof p', 'object' ]
console.log(['p.name', p.name]); // "anonymous"
```

Given an object, how can view all the properties I can access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is just for debugging, you can check the [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) object:

```
function Person() {};
Person.prototype.name = "abc";
Person.prototype.smallObj = {
    name: "abc"
};

Person.prototype.deepObj = {
    one: {
        two: {
            three: {
                four: "4"
            }
        }
    }
};

var p = new Person();

console.log(p);
// Person {}

console.log(p.__proto__);
/*
Person {
    name: 'abc',
    smallObj: { name: 'abc' },
    deepObj: { one: { two: [Object] } }
}
*/
var util = require("util");
console.log(util.inspect(p.__proto__, {depth: null}));
/*
Person {
    name: 'abc',
    smallObj: { name: 'abc' },
    deepObj: { one: { two: { three: { four: '4' } } } }
}
*/
```

On the last one, using [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) with the `depth` option will allow you to look further into deeply nested objects.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning property to constructor function `Person`. It does not share properties with instances. You need to add property to `Person`'s prototype:

```
Person.prototype.name = "anonymous";
```

To find out if your object inherited from `Person` you can do:

```
p instanceof Person; // true
```

You can print out all of an object's enumerable properties by performing the following:

```
for (var key in p) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected the example to fix the prototype. `for ... in ...` is helpful, is there a function for this?

Comment: I don't see how I can use `instanceof` to answer the question "is this value a simple object, or has it inherited from something?"

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to get all properties that belong to an object:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Person))
// [ 'length', 'name', 'arguments', 'caller', 'prototype' ]

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object))
// ['length','name','arguments','caller','prototype','keys','create',  'defineProperty','defineProperties','freeze','getPrototypeOf','setPrototypeOf','getOwnPropertyDescriptor','getOwnPropertyNames','is','isExtensible','isFrozen','isSealed','preventExtensions','seal','getOwnPropertySymbols','deliverChangeRecords','getNotifier','observe','unobserve','assign' ]
```

Also you can combine `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` with walking up the prototype chain:

```
var getAllProperties = function (object) {

  var properties = []
  do {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).forEach((prop) => {
      if (!~properties.indexOf(prop)) {
        properties.push(prop)
      }
    })
  } while (object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object))

  return properties
}
```